# CABasicAnimation on layer does not execute

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, quartz-graphics

I'm trying to add a simple glow animation to a UIButton (inside a TableViewCell inside a UITableViewController).

However, the animation doesn't seem to execute, even when I whittle it down to its simplest possible form.

On further research, it seems that the layer properties cannot be animated using animateWithDuration:, so here's my attempt using CABasicAnimation:

```
view.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
view.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;
view.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero;

[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"Animation complete.");
}];
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"shadowRadius"];
animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:50.0.0f];
animation.duration = 2.0;
[view.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"shadowRadius"];
[CATransaction commit];
```

The animation duration is correct, but no matter what property I attempt to animate in this transaction (I've tried several from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/AnimatableProperties/AnimatableProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH11-SW4)), no visible changes are made over the course of the animation.  This is almost identical to the example [from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CreatingBasicAnimations/CreatingBasicAnimations.html), but clearly I'm missing something - anyone have an idea what it is?

Comment: I've tried running your code and I get a rotating view with a shadow. Isn't that what you're trying to perform?

Comment: Yes, that's what you should get out of the first one.  I gather that it must be something specific to trying to animate a UIButton just after it is tapped, then, or a UIButton inside a UITableViewCell.  I will update the question if I am able to trim down my view code enough to provide the whole thing...